# How to edit password protected(Encrypted) PDF files in code

Tags: pdf, pdf.js

My application appends signatrues to the end of PDF files. I have now run into the issue of password protected and Encrypted files. Given that i have the passwors to the PDF how can i edit the file, what do i need to do?

Currently im using PDF.js to read and parse the file and to access the XREF and obj of PDF. I create my own aobj and append it to the end of the PDF file in a valid format for PDF readers. But if i do the same with files that are encrypted the data becomes corrupted. What do i need to do differently with encrypted files?

Comment: You are adding crypto graphic digital signatures? Or just a visual signature? Also, are you doing the editing "manually" yourself, or are you using a PDF library to make the edits? Which library? If yourself, then everything you need to know is in the PDF file specification...

Comment: crypto digital signature. And doing it manually. Been reading the PDF spec but im not fully sure what i must do for it to work. Do i need to decrypt the file, then remove crypt add my signature and recrypt it, or can i just append to it, and encrypt the part i added. This is the unclear bit.

Comment: You should use a PDF SDK. You will save your self a lot of time, and a lot of bugs/issues down the road, if you use a PDF processing library, rather than trying to do this yourself.

Comment: I have been unable to find a Javascript PDF libary that does what I need for it to do. I need to be able to add a custom widget type and all signatures must be appended to the end of file, the original content must not be changed. I found few libaries that allow for modification of PDF but they always completely changed the original structure.

Comment: Why is javascript important? You want to do this all client side in the browser? If so, why is that important? Why not do this server side?

Comment: There app works on client side only. We only have a webserver that serves the HTML and JS. There is no backend server.

Comment: Trying to edit a PDF file completely client side in the browser definitely limits your options. Are you open to a paid commercial library, like the one developed by the company I work for?

Comment: That is not my decision. And the looks of it says that probably not.